# With out using DISTINCT / GROUP BY how to fetch unique row of data from mysql5 table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, left-join

I have one image table and image view status table.

In each click of image I am tracking image view time. status. date time.. So in image view status table have more than one entry for one image.

I need to check whether one user already viewed one image or not.

So I write one query like this..

`select A.title, if(B.view_status='completed','completed','notviewed') from images A left join imgstatus_view B on (A.imgId=B.ImgId and A.fileId=B.fileID) Where userId=1 and imgId=121`

If I view one image three times its fetching 3 records. I need only one record to check whether user viewed the image or not.

So with out using `DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` How can I fetch unique row of data.

Please help me.

Comment: Why the restriction on `distinct` and `group by`?

Comment: Did you verify it to be an issue? You have numbers to support this? Or you just "heard" somewhere that it "could be" an issue?

Comment: yes I read some where DISTINCT / GROUP BY is more expensive

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use ORDER BY and LIMIT clause. to get most recent record you can use below query

```
select A.title, if(B.view_status='completed','completed','notviewed') from images A left join imgstatus_view B on (A.imgId=B.ImgId and A.fileId=B.fileID) Where userId=1 and imgId=121 ORDER BY datetimefield DESC LIMIT 0,1
```

to get old record

```
select A.title, if(B.view_status='completed','completed','notviewed') from images A left join imgstatus_view B on (A.imgId=B.ImgId and A.fileId=B.fileID) Where userId=1 and imgId=121 ORDER BY datetimefield LIMIT 0,1
```

if you dont have datetime field remove ORDER BY clause which will give most recent modified record